# What does `LESS=+/EXAMPLE\:` mean?

Tags: less, man, symbols

In `man parallel_tutorial` (for GNU parallel) I’ve found the following black magic:

```
LESS=+/EXAMPLE\: man parallel
```

Searching around in the `man` pages for `man`, `less`, and `bash`, it appears this may have something to do with a `less` *preprocessor*, but I’m not sure, and the first few attempts I made to search other manual pages with this syntax failed.

What does `+/...\:` mean in bash?

Comment: Your highlight section does not have \:  The back-slash is missing.  Did you mean to?

Comment: @mike65535 , it is typed in, if you hit 'edit', you can see it. It doesn't get displayed though.

Comment: Escaping the \ with another backslash should work. To short for me to edit though.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't mean anything *in bash*. It's some arbitrary text that gets stored in the $LESS environment variable for that single command.

But when you run `less`, it reads the contents of $LESS and interprets them much like command-line arguments. Usually this is where you'd store configuration for it.

(*less* is not a preprocessor: it's a simple text file viewer, aka a pager. Note that `man` has no built-in reader: it just generates the text via *groff* (the actual preprocessor), then always runs either *less* or some other pager to scroll through it. The authors of that tutorial assume your system will be using *less* because it's so ubiquitous.)

When *less* encounters arguments starting with a `+`, the remainder is further interpreted as commands or keypresses to simulate: e.g. if it were `+G` then less would pretend you had pressed G after opening the file, and would scroll down.

In your case, *less* pretends you had typed `/EXAMPLE:` after opening the file. <kbd>/</kbd> is the search key/command in *less*, and the rest is the text to search for.

The result is that the command opens the manpage of "parallel", then scrolls down to the section titled "EXAMPLE".

Comment: Which the tutorial's author apparently found too difficult to express in ordinary English.

Comment: Well, it's *is* GNU... :P Excellent answer btw, popped up just as I began writing so good timing too!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the back-slash before the colon _is_ relevant to `bash`, as it stops the colon from having a special meaning, which it doesn't have in `bash`, though it may in another shell.

Comment: @grawity The context in the tutorial is: "Then look at the EXAMPLEs after the list of OPTIONS in man parallel (Use LESS=+/EXAMPLE\: man parallel)". How would you have expressed it in ordinary English?

Answer (score 7):

As [grawity's excellent answer indicates](https://superuser.com/a/1322061/461558), it's a way of giving an instruction to the `less` pager. In this specific case, using the manual and tutorial of GNU Parallel, it makes reading the examples easy.

As you can see from even the table of contents in the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html), each example starts with the string `EXAMPLE:`, so the command `LESS=+/EXAMPLE: man parallel` lets you jump to the fist example, **and subsequent examples** by pressing <kbd>n</kbd> (for *next match*).

For example:

[image: screencap of jumping through manual]

(*each jump in manual section is a <kbd>n</kbd> keypress*)